# How to count enum data MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

all please help me.. 
i've table like this e.q = table1

```
Name | status |
donez  open
donez  closed
donez  reopen
donez  closed
alex   open
```

i need to show data like this :

```
    Name   |            Total                   |
-------------------------------------------------
    donez  | open = 1 | closed = 2 | reopen = 1 |
-------------------------------------------------
    alex   | open = 1 | closed = 0 | reopen = 0 |
-------------------------------------------------
```

please help me, Name type = Varchar, Status type = ENUM.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
  select name ,
  sum(CASE WHEN status = 'open' then 1 else 0 end )as total_open,
  sum(CASE WHEN status = 'closed' then 1 else 0 end) as total_closed,
  sum(CASE WHEN status = 'reopen' then 1 else 0 end )as total_reopen
  from table1
  group by name
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5024d/1)

add this in the end if you want get result ordered as you wished.

```
 order by name desc
```

Comment: yes does not matter if its enum or varchar we can always get the sum this way or `select
name,
sum(status='open') as `open`,
sum(status='closed') as `closed`,
sum(status='reopen') as `reopen`
from test 
group by name`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty yes . it doesnt play role , just sum them.